# Can I get a Turkish transit visa at Istanbul airport?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, turkey, irish-citizens

I am an Irish citizen and travelling to Nigeria through istanbul. can i get the transit visa at the airport since my transit time is about 14 hours?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ie&DE=tr&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for holders of normal passports issued
>   to nationals of Ireland (Rep.) can obtain a visa or an e-visa
>   on arrival, for a max. stay of 3 months. The e-visa can also
>   be obtained online prior to departure at www.evisa.gov.tr.

In other words, you can either apply through the website, **or** through kiosks at Istanbul airport.

[Online it costs USD 20, while at the airport it costs USD 30 (or EUR 25, or GBP 20)](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/data/KONSOLOSLUK/e-visa-fees-en-31-december.pdf)